# Bootstrap flipping cards row is not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with responsive in bootstrap.
When I have over four cards they are not "jump" into next row. They only Impose itself andthis same is when I'm resizing viev.
What Can I do to fix it? I'm fresh in bootstrap and maybe I'm doing something wrong with CSS file.
Can you help me how fix it?

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000px;
}
 /* flip the pane when hovered */
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }



/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
   
   
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;  background-color: green;">
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
  
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: green; line-height: 80px;">
            <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>



<div class="container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 <div class="flip-container "    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"   >
  <div class="card-block"   >
   <div class="flipper " >
 
      <div class="front " style="background-color: grey;" >
        <img class="img-fluid col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="image.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="padding: 5px;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="back  " style="background-color: grey;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    
   </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 <div class="flip-container "    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"   >
  <div class="card-block"   >
   <div class="flipper " >
 
      <div class="front " style="background-color: grey;" >
        <img class="img-fluid col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="image.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="padding: 5px;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="back  " style="background-color: grey;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    
   </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 <div class="flip-container "    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"   >
  <div class="card-block"   >
   <div class="flipper " >
 
      <div class="front " style="background-color: grey;" >
        <img class="img-fluid col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="image.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="padding: 5px;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="back  " style="background-color: grey;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    
   </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 <div class="flip-container "    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"   >
  <div class="card-block"   >
   <div class="flipper " >
 
      <div class="front " style="background-color: grey;" >
        <img class="img-fluid col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="image.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="padding: 5px;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="back  " style="background-color: grey;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    
   </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 <div class="flip-container "    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"   >
  <div class="card-block"   >
   <div class="flipper " >
 
      <div class="front " style="background-color: grey;" >
        <img class="img-fluid col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="image.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="padding: 5px;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="back  " style="background-color: grey;">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    
   </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


</div>

 


</body>
</html>
```